# Adding variable in constructor automatically + eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to find a plugin or some shortcut that does exist in eclipse for this feature.

Basically is there any shortcut which if I press would lead to form a constructor with all the public variables of the class being defined in it ?

So if I have a Student class like this

```
public class Student{
   public String name;
   public int age;
}
```

Then pressing the shortcut leads to

```
Student( String name , int age ){
   this.age = age;
   this.name = name;
}
```

It is quite difficult to have specific ones but does there exist any feature to get all of the variables assigned ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click in the editor and click

> Source -> Generate Constructor using Fields

You can select the super constructor to use and also select instance variables to add to the constructor.

Taken directly from : [how to generate constructors in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484867/how-to-generate-constuctors-in-eclipse/3484882#3484882)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ALT+Shift+S for generating constructor by using fields (you can choose the variable that you want use) or from the Super class directly